# php class file extension being set as java class file instead

Tags: php, class, dreamweaver

I am using dreamweaver on a Mac and am trying to save a file as "template.class.php" in the dreamweaver dialog box that opens up when you save something. Then in my script I am using the  "include" construct to include the file as in:

```
require_once( $object . '.class.php' );
```

but am getting an error message

```
"Fatal error: Class 'template' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/web_development/MVC/registry/registry.class.php on line 28"
```

So i used notepad++ on windows to solve this problem which was that the files needed to be named "template.class" while still retaining the fact that it's a php file and not a Java class file. I want to know how I can do the same on a mac.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't add the `.php` on most web servers you'll be able to view the source when browsing to the page (which is really bad).

Comment: Dreamweaver isn't really a very good php editor. For that, you should use just a regular text editor.

Comment: Which one in a mac environment?